# How to keep Flutter app running on lock/sleep screen (geolocator and timer builder)?

Tags: flutter, timer, geolocation

I have a screen on my app that tracks the location (`geolocator`) and time with (`timer_builder`) when the user hits start button. When the screen locks/sleeps, it stops (or pause) tracking the location, but it should pause just when the user hits the stop button.
Could anyone help me on this?

I believe there is difference between running the app `on background` vs `on lock screen`, because I just found topics about running the app on background with android_alarm_manager/background_fetch (on this case awaken app in the background about every 15 minutes would not work too).
One solution would be prevent screen from going into sleep/lock mode, but then battery is problem. Any other solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think background geolocation is a hard problem. However there is a project, [flutter_background_geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_geolocation). It works with debug mode. Unfortunately, in release mode, you need to purchase a license.

Comment: but is lock screen considered background?
It looks like `flutter_background_geolocation` is more complicate from what I need (and I am trying to avoid this $300 license haha on my currency it is too much)

Answer (score 1):

You can create background tasks with Flutter, see [this article](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124). Never tried it though.